# Add drop-down in angular calendar for changing Activity status

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-calendar

I'am using angular-calendar with a custom template as given here : https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/custom-templates,

What i want to do :- i want a dropdown box inside my day-cell for changing Activity status (succeed,pending,rejected)

What's the problem occurs :- when i use custom template and add it in mwl-calendar-month-view with  [cellTemplate]="customcellTemplate" the *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Month" stop Working when i want both together.

i want the view like this  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvGuo.png)

Edit

What i have tried :

```
<mwl-calendar-month-view
    [cellTemplate]="custom"
    *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Month"
    [viewDate]="viewDate"
    [events]="events"
    [refresh]="refresh"
    [activeDayIsOpen]="activeDayIsOpen"
    (dayClicked)="dayClicked($event.day)"
    (eventClicked)="handleEvent('Clicked', $event.event)"
    (eventTimesChanged)="eventTimesChanged($event)"
  >
  
  </mwl-calendar-month-view>
  <ng-template name="" id="" #custom  let-day="day" >
  
    <select name="" id="">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
  </ng-template>
```

Output : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1sKz.png)